# Windows Update Agent API - Searching for Updates

Tags: windows, powershell

I wrote a Powershell script that uses the Windows Update Agent API (IUpdateSearcher, IUpdateDownloader, IUpdateInstaller etc.). Everything works fine, the script finds avaiable updates, downloads and installs them.

However, there is a problem when searching for consecutive updates. For example, there is an update for the .Net Framework 4.5.2. The update is installed by script and the PC is rebooted afterwards. Now there should be an update for the .Net Framework 4.5.2 Language Pack avaiable.

But it is not. At least not via the API. A manual search with the GUI (Windows Update) works.

After the manual search, the API finds the update a well!

What am I missing in my script? I could not find anything in Microsofts documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386868(v=vs.85).aspx

```
$updateSession = New-Object -ComObject 'Microsoft.Update.Session'
$UpdateSession.WebProxy.AutoDetect = $false

$updateSearcher = $updateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()

$searchResult = $updateSearcher.Search('IsInstalled=0 and IsHidden=0')

$objCollectionDownload = New-Object -ComObject 'Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl'

foreach ($update in $searchResult.Updates)
{
    $objCollectionTmp = New-Object -ComObject 'Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl'
    $objCollectionTmp.Add($update) | Out-Null

    $downloader = $updateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader()
    $downloader.Updates = $objCollectionTmp

    try
    {
        $downloadResult = $downloader.Download()
    }
    catch
    {
        //exception Handling
    }

    $objCollectionDownload.Add($update) | Out-Null
}

$updatesToInstall = New-Object -ComObject 'Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl'
$updateInstaller = $updateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller()

foreach ($update in $objCollectionDownload)
{
    //accept Eula etc...

    $updatesToInstall.Add($update) | Out-Null
}

$updateInstaller.Updates = $updatesToInstall

$installationRestult = $updateInstaller.Install()

//check installation result
```

Comment: It's always worked for me, though I haven't tested that particular combination of updates.  Apart from the fact that I'm using vbscript instead of Powershell, the only difference is that I say `.Search("IsInstalled=0")` without the extra clause, perhaps try that?

Comment: Besides this bug, the script works fine for me, too. I had the same issue installing IE10, the consecutive security updates for IE10 were not found with the search method. I will try `.Search("IsInstalled=0")`

Comment: Huh.  As it happens we skipped IE10, went directly from IE9 to IE11.  And we haven't deployed 4.5.2 yet, and I'm not sure whether the WSUS server is configured to include language packs anyway.  So I'm guessing I just haven't hit the particular circumstances that trigger the bug.  You might want to try stopping and restarting the Windows Update service (wuauserv).

Answer (score 3):

Oddly enough I had the same issue just now, Windows GUI showed a particular update, Our GUI using the API wouldn't show this particular update... I had IsInstalled = 0 and IsHidden = 0.... I looked in the WIndows Update log and found the criteria that the WIndows GUI was using.

IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Installation' or IsPresent=1 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' or IsInstalled=1 and DeploymentAction='Installation' and RebootRequired=1 or IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' and RebootRequired=1

Added this to my application in place of IsInstalled = 0 and IsHidden = 0 and the update showed straight up :-/ don't really understand why but I am not complaining.